# Artificially defined curve contradicts the Hasse bound, what is wrong

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

We got artificially defined curve over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ of genus $1$
and only two projective points and this contradict the Hasse bound
on number of points over finite fields. The curve has only
one singular projective point.

For $p=11$ the affine curve is:
$$
(1) \qquad x^3-y^3- 1=0
$$
$$
(2) \qquad 1=z x (x-1) (x-2) (x-3) (x-4) (x-5) (x-6) (x-7) (x-8)(x-9) (x-10)
$$

(2) is essentially disequality constraint.

What is wrong with this violation of the Hasse bound?

Possible problem could be the singular point, but projective closure
of hyperelliptic curve also have singular point.

Comment: Basically the problem is that you introduced an "artificial" third coordinate $z=1/(x^{11}-x)$ that has a pole at all the affine points of $x^3-y^3=1$. The Hasse-Weil bound really says something about the number of degree one places (=discrete valuation rings with residue class fields equal to the field of constants) of the function field $K=\Bbb{F}_{11}(x,y)$. See e.g. Stichtenoth's books. The element $z=1/(x^{11}-x)$ is already an element of $K$, so it is not going to change anything. In other words $K(z)=K$.

Comment: But, admittedly that sounds unsatisfactory. I'm so used to thinking about questions like these in terms of the function field that the above is my "go to"- explanation. On a smooth model of a function field those degree one places do correspond bijectively with $\Bbb{F}_q$-rational points. Going to a projective closure should remedy things. Thinking...

Comment: This is not unlike complaining about the same thing wth the genus zero curve $1=z(x^{11}-x)$. Having genus one is just a distraction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. I don't understand all comments, are they answer of just partial results?

Comment: Not an answer. More like thinking aloud. I'm still in the process of consuming my morning coffee :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am having coffee too, cheers. The Hasse upper bound can be attacked with singular points like: $y^2=(x^3+1) (x(x-1)*(x-3)\cdots) ^2$ but this attack is obvious.

Comment: A bail out is that Hasse-Weil applies only to smooth projective curves. The usual projective closure of even $1=z(x^{11}-x)$, namely $W^{12}=Z(X^{11}-XW^{10})$ has a singularity at $(X:Z:W)=(0:1:0)$ ruining the day. In general one needs to go to a smooth model of the function field to be sure to be able to apply Hasse-Weil. In the case of your curve the simple way of getting that smooth model is to basically ignore the second equation, and go to the projective closure. Then we get back to my first comment.

Comment: There may be a way of adjusting Hasse-Weil, when singular points are present, but I don't remember/know how to do that. Anyway, *you are not counting points on a smooth projective curve, so Hasse-Weil does not apply.* Wish I could say more in this small space :-( - we need an expert to show up. The route via function fields really makes problems like these go Poof!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. Is this open enough to crosspost to mathoverflow or did you answer it? The projective closures of $x^4-1=y^2,x^5-1=y^2$ have singular points too, how do you bound points on them?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235637878_Weil_Theorem_for_Singular_curves Weil Theorem for Singular curves

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 
The number of points on an algebraic curve over a finite field https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~ftorres/RESEARCH/ARTS_PDF/hkt_sur.pdf

Comment: I am not aware of a result tying the nature/number of singular terms to an extra error term in Hasse-Weil. A superquick reading of a few of your links didn't reveal such either. I would use bounds on character sums to find the number of points on those hyperelliptic curves. I do think that a properly formulated version of this could be well received in MathOverflow. Felipe Voloch (among others) checks out MO frequently, and the papers you linked to refer to his results.

Comment: The mechanism of using extraneous coordinates coming from rational functions with poles at all the rational points may be a known trick producing bad singularities in view of error terms to Hasse-Weil.

Comment: If you post a version of this to MO, please crosslink the two questions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen OK. I don't understand algebraic geometry and am trying to formulate sound question. Found that univariate Hasse requires smoothness and this is an answer. Would you help with formulation or possibly ask it yourself on MO crosslinking? There could be other similar tricks with dummy variables.